# Update column with data in rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I have an events table and sessions table. Events has_many sessions, this is the association. Now I want to move the time_zone column from the sessions table to events table only. So how do I do this with help of migrations. How do I move the existing records for time_zone in sessions table to events table?

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to be sure that sessions associated with the same event have the same time zone. You can do this with:

```
Session.group(:event_id).count(:time_zone)
```

This will return a hash mapping an `event_id` to the number of time zones associated with it. This number should always be one.

Second, I recommend that you first add `events.time_zone` and start using it and remove `sessions.time_zone` in a separate migration after the new code has been in production for some time and is proved to work.

Third, the migration to add `events.time_zone` should look like this (I added some comments for clarity):

```
class AddTimeZoneToEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  class Event < ActiveRecord::Base; end
  class Session < ActiveRecord::Base; end

  def up
    # Add a NULLable time_zone column to events. Even if the column should be
    # non-NULLable, we first allow NULLs and will set the appropriate values
    # in the next step.
    add_column :events, :time_zone, :string

    # Ensure the new column is visible.
    Event.reset_column_information

    # Iterate over events in batches. Use #update_columns to set the newly
    # added time_zone without modifying updated_at. If you want to update
    # updated_at you have at least two options:
    #
    #   1. Set it to the time at which the migration is run. In this case, just
    #      replace #update_columns with #update!
    #   2. Set it to the maximum of `events.updated_at` and
    #      `sessions.updated_at`.
    #
    # Also, if your database is huge you may consider a different query to
    # perform the update (it also depends on your database).
    Event.find_each do |event|
      session = Session.where(event_id: event.id).last
      event.update_columns(time_zone: session.time_zone)
    end

    # If events don't always need to have time zone information then
    # you can remove the line below.
    change_column_null :events, :time_zone, false
  end

  def down
    remove_column :events, :time_zone
  end
end
```

Note that I redefined models in the migration. It's crucial to do so because:

1. The original model may have callbacks and validations (sure, you can skip them but it's one extra precaution that contributes zero value).
2. If you remove the models in 6 months down the road the migration will stop working.

Once you're sure your changes work as expected you can remove `sessions.time_zone`. If something goes awry you can simply roll back the above migration and restore a working version easily.

Comment: This works. What in case of down, shouldn't there be any method that would restore the time_zone in sessions table?

Comment: Notice that I did **not** remove `sessions.time_zone`. See the last paragraph - I recommend you first migrate to the new column, make your code use it and once you're sure it works remove the old column. Database storage is cheap so there's no rush.

Comment: Oh.. I missed that part.. this helps then.. 
will it make sense to create a third table to store the associations something like events_sessions table?

Comment: Tables like this are used in many-to-many relationships. If I understand your case correctly, the time zone of a session should come from the corresponding event. In this case, it doesn't make sense to create a table like this. You can delegate `Session#time_zone` to `Event#time_zone` with `def time_zone; event.time_zone; end` or `delegate_to`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the following migration.

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :events, :time_zone, :string

    Event.all.each do |e|
      e.update_attributes(time_zone: e.sessions.last.time_zone)
    end

    remove_column :sessions, :time_zone
  end
end
```

Comment: You shouldn't use models in migrations. They can trigger callbacks, validations, etc. plus they can change with time (i.e. if you remove the model in 6 months the migration will stop working).